# No Pi superscript in unicode?

Tags: javascript, unicode, pi, superscript

How can you display pi superscript if it's not in Unicode? It's for a javascript program I'm making. I can't think of any way around it.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting its size and position with css?

Comment: What do you mean by "*if it's not in Unicode*"? What javascript program are you making? What does it display, how, where, with what code?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350441/is-there-an-unicode-symbol-for-superscript-comma

Comment: all those questions make me realize I barely know what I'm making haha. I'm kind of winging this program without really having learned JavaScript, Basically, it's a program that based on the current time displays certain messages. I want to display Euler's identity at a certain time (so this happens in a script inside a body tag for html) i've been doing document.getElementById("textDisplay").innerText = "whatever"; for whatever time I want. and using unicode in the "whatever" part but i can't put superscript pi in there. Not sure if this is clearer at all. But appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 4):

No specific Superscript-PI in Unicode yet,
but the U+2DEB    ⷫ  "Combining Cyrillic Letter Pe"  is closest, i think, At this point.
And there are other PI look-alike or alternatives character/symbol in various writing languages that is written-as & appears-like a superscript PI = Π = π :

```
U+2DEB  -  ⷫ - Combining Cyrillic Letter Pe.
U+1D54  - ᵔ  - Modifier Letter Small Top Half O.
U+1D16  - ᴖ  - Latin Small Letter Top Half O.
U+2DE7  -  ⷧ - Combining Cyrillic Letter El.
U+A66F  -  ꙯ - Combining Cyrillic Vzmet.
U+0346  - ◌͆ - Combining Bridge Above.
U+0311  - ◌̑ - Combining Inverted Breve/Arch.
U+1FC0  - ῀  - Greek Perispomeni.
U+0A70  -  ੰ - Gurmukhi Tippi.
U+1422  - ᐢ  - Canadian Syllabics Final Top Half Ring.
U+18D5  - ᣕ  - Canadian Syllabics Ojibway T.
U+1D1AA -    - Musical Symbol Combining Down Bow.
U+1E135 -   - Nyiakeng Puachue Hmong Tone-G.
U+A8B6  -  ꢶ - Saurashtra Vowel Sign I.
U+1A65  -  ᩥ - Thai Tham Vowel Sign I.
U+0EB4  -   ິ - Lao Vowel Sign I.
U+1B3X  -   ᬶ - Balinese Vowel Sign Ulu.
U+17DD  -   ៝ - Khmer Sign Atthacan.
```

Examples:
｜ Eular's Identity ｜ "n-th roots of unity" ｜

To view Unicode chars from various ranges, you need [Unicode-fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode%5Ffont). For Windows & MacOS & Linux/Unix you will need to obtain `*.ttf`, etc font file(s) & place inside Font folder. For Android try [iFont](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kapp.ifont) or other font installer type of app. For iOS(iPhone) try [Font Diner](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/font-diner/id1480286620) or other font installer type of app.

by using Unicode characters:
｜  ⷫⁱ + 1 = 0 ｜ ² ⷫⁱᵏᐟⁿ (=0,1,2,...,-1) ｜ (just Unicode chars. No space-chars).
｜   ⷫ ⁱ + 1 = 0 ｜ ²  ⷫ ⁱ ᵏᐟⁿ (=0,1,2,...,-1) ｜(sp in left of  ⷫ & ⁱ).
exact code: ｜ `&#8239; ⷫ&#8202;ⁱ + 1 = 0` ｜ `²&#8239; ⷫ&#8202;ⁱ&#8202;ᵏᐟⁿ` (`=0,1,2,...,-1`) ｜
above info will wrap so user can see w/o sliding left-right,
in below box user have to slide right-left to see above same info:

```
｜  ⷫⁱ + 1 = 0 ｜ ² ⷫⁱᵏᐟⁿ (=0,1,2,...,-1) ｜ (just Unicode chars. No space-chars).  
｜   ⷫ ⁱ + 1 = 0 ｜ ²  ⷫ ⁱ ᵏᐟⁿ (=0,1,2,...,-1) ｜(sp in left of  ⷫ & ⁱ).  
exact code: ｜ `&#8239; ⷫ&#8202;ⁱ + 1 = 0` ｜ `²&#8239; ⷫ&#8202;ⁱ&#8202;ᵏᐟⁿ` (`=0,1,2,...,-1`) ｜
```

｜    ⷫ ⁱ + 1 = 0 ｜  ²   ⷫ ⁱ ᵏᐟⁿ (=0,1,2,...,-1) ｜ (more sp-chars. No `<i>...</i>`).
exact code: ｜ `&#8239;&#8239; ⷫ&#8239;ⁱ + 1 = 0` ｜ `&#8202;²&#8239;&#8239; ⷫ&#8239;ⁱ&#8202;ᵏᐟⁿ` (`=0,1,2,...,-1`) ｜
above info will wrap so user can see w/o sliding left-right,
in below box user have to slide right-left to see above same info:

```
｜    ⷫ ⁱ + 1 = 0 ｜  ²   ⷫ ⁱ ᵏᐟⁿ (=0,1,2,...,-1) ｜ (more sp-chars. No `...`).  
exact code: ｜ `&#8239;&#8239; ⷫ&#8239;ⁱ + 1 = 0` ｜ `&#8202;²&#8239;&#8239; ⷫ&#8239;ⁱ&#8202;ᵏᐟⁿ` (`=0,1,2,...,-1`) ｜
```

｜   *ⷫ* ***ⁱ*** + 1 = 0 ｜  ²  *ⷫ* ***ⁱ*** *ᵏᐟⁿ* (=0,1,2,...,-1) ｜ (more sp-chars & w/`<i>...</i>`,`<b>...</b>`).
exact code: ｜ `&#8239;<i> ⷫ</i>&#8239;<b><i>ⁱ</i></b> + 1 = 0` ｜ `&#8202;²&#8239;<i> ⷫ</i>&#8239;<b><i>ⁱ</i></b>&#8202;<i>ᵏᐟⁿ</i>` (`=0,1,2,...,-1`) ｜
above info will wrap so user can see w/o sliding left-right,
in below box user have to slide right-left to see above same info:

```
｜   ⷫ ⁱ + 1 = 0 ｜  ²  ⷫ ⁱ ᵏᐟⁿ (=0,1,2,...,-1) ｜ (more sp-chars & w/`...`,`...`).  
exact code: ｜ `&#8239; ⷫ&#8239;ⁱ + 1 = 0` ｜ `&#8202;²&#8239; ⷫ&#8239;ⁱ&#8202;ᵏᐟⁿ` (`=0,1,2,...,-1`) ｜
```

by using HTML `<sup>...</sup>`, `<i>...</i>`, `<b>...</b>`, etc tags:
｜ *e<sup>πi</sup>* + 1 = 0 ｜ *e*<sup>2</sup>*<sup>πik**/**n</sup>* (*k*=0,1,2,...,*n*-1) ｜ (just regular Basic latin chars. No sp-chars).
exact code: ｜ `<i>e<sup>πi</sup></i> + 1 = 0` ｜ `<i>e</i><sup>2</sup><i><sup>πik<b>/</b>n</sup></i>` (`<i>k</i>=0,1,2,...,<i>n</i>-1`) ｜
above info will wrap so user can see w/o sliding left-right,
in below box user have to slide right-left to see above same info:

```
｜ eπi + 1 = 0 ｜ e2πik/n (k=0,1,2,...,n-1) ｜ (just regular Basic latin chars. No sp-chars).  
exact code: ｜ `<i>e<sup>πi</sup></i> + 1 = 0` ｜ `<i>e</i><sup>2</sup><i><sup>πik<b>/</b>n</sup></i>` (`<i>k</i>=0,1,2,...,<i>n</i>-1`) ｜
```

｜ *e<sup>π i</sup>* + 1 = 0 ｜ *e*<sup>2</sup>*<sup>π i k **/** n</sup>* (*k*=0,1,2,...,*n*-1) ｜ (sp-chars are used).
exact code: ｜ `<i>e<sup>π&#8202;i</sup></i> + 1 = 0` ｜ `<i>e</i><sup>2</sup><i><sup>π&#8202;i&#8202;k&#8202;<b>/</b>&#8202;n</sup></i>` (`<i>k</i>=0,1,2,...,<i>n</i>-1`)
above info will wrap so user can see w/o sliding left-right,
in below box user have to slide right-left to see above same info:

```
｜ eπ i + 1 = 0 ｜ e2π i k / n (k=0,1,2,...,n-1) ｜ (sp-chars are used).  
exact code: ｜ `<i>e<sup>π i</sup></i> + 1 = 0` ｜ `<i>e</i><sup>2</sup><i><sup>π i k <b>/</b> n</sup></i>` (`<i>k</i>=0,1,2,...,<i>n</i>-1`)
```

｜ Unicode-CP｜Char｜`Char`｜ brief info ｜
｜----------------｜--------｜--------｜------------｜
｜ U+212F ｜ ℯ ｜ `ℯ` ｜ script small-e (Eular's number) ｜
｜ U+1D452 ｜  ｜  ｜ math. italic small-e ｜
｜ U+1D486 ｜  ｜  ｜ math. bold-italic small-e ｜
｜ U+1D626 ｜   ｜  ｜ math. sans-serif italic small-e ｜
｜ U+1D65A ｜  ｜  ｜ math. sans-serif bold italic small-e ｜
｜ U+1D458 ｜  ｜  ｜ math. italic small-k ｜
｜ U+1D4F7 ｜  ｜  ｜ math. bold script small-n ｜
｜ U+1D70B ｜  ｜  ｜ math. italic small pi ｜
｜ U+29F8 ｜ ⧸ ｜ `⧸` ｜ big solidus ｜
｜ U+2215 ｜ ∕ ｜ `∕` ｜ division slash ｜
｜ U+2071 ｜ ⁱ ｜ `ⁱ` ｜ superscript latin small letter i ｜
｜ U+207F ｜ ⁿ ｜ `ⁿ` ｜ superscript latin small letter n ｜
｜ U+1D4F ｜ ᵏ ｜ `ᵏ` ｜ modifier letter small-k ｜
｜ U+00B2 ｜ ² ｜ `²` ｜ superscript two ｜
｜ U+141F ｜ ᐟ ｜ `ᐟ` ｜ canadian syllabics final acute ｜

Actual SP(space)-char is inside the single-quotes:
｜ U+202F ｜' ' (d)｜' ' (h)｜&#8239;｜ Narrow No-Break Space (NNBSP)   ｜
｜ U+200A ｜' ' (d)｜' ' (h)｜&#8202;｜ Hair Space (HSP)    ｜
｜ U+200D ｜'‍' (d)｜'‍' (h)｜&#8205;｜ Zero Width Joiner (ZWJ) ｜

You may also see CSS3 feature [font-stretch](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-stretch-prop) to narrow/wide a character.

To use/display any of these Unicode chars, either use the Unicode-codepoint `U+uuuu` like this **:** Get the `uuuu` (hexa-decimal) numbers after the `U+`, and place those numbers after this `&#x` symbols, & end with one semicolon `;` symbol, like these**:** `&#xuuuu;`
or, if HTML decimal entity number is shown for a Unicode char, then use the decimal numbers `dddd` after this `&#` symbols, & end with one semicolon `;` symbol, like this**:** `&#dddd;`

References:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Answer (score 1):

If this question is about HTML, try [`<sup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup)

```
e<sup>i&pi;</sup>
```

displays as

> e<sup>iπ</sup>

Comment: It's in a script inside of the HTML body so no it's not exactly that. But that's very useful either case thank you.